# Windows 7 - Sharing a connection through WiFi?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ad-hoc-network, connection-sharing

I have a PC with Windows 7 and an iPod Touch.

Windows 7 is connected to the Internet through a 3G dongle; I have set up an ad hoc WiFi network and ticked "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection".

[image]

---

I have connected to both networks, but I'm getting "No Internet access" as access type for the Ad Hoc connection.

[image]

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tick the sharing box on the other Network (Ad-Hoc BLAM) instead of in the vodafone Network.

Answer (score 1):

The "Local Area Connection" is your wired ethernet. If it doesn't show your wireless card in your "Home Networking Connection" then something is wrong. In fact on your desktop, it probably won't show that the wireless connection has an internet connection because that would require 2 gateways (1 for the 3G card and 1 for the wireless; this is so Windows would be able to test internet connectivity for each of the connections).